# CloudFlare "SSL: Flexible" HTTPS not working on custom ports

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, digital-ocean, cloudflare

I have my domain on CloudFlare pointing at DigitalOcean Droplet's IP Address. While trying to access website through domain on CloudFlare using custom ports I get: `error 525 SSL handshake failed`. My CloudFlare `Crypto SSL is set to: Flexible` (...as I understand - no SSL is required on DigitalOcean droplet).

---

**Example addresses:**

Through **DigitalOcean IPv4** (no SSL installed on server)

http://46.101.xxx.xxx/ *- 100% working*

https://46.101.xxx.xxx/ *- 0% not working at all (server set up for :80)*

http://46.101.xxx.xxx:2053/api *- 100% working*

http://46.101.xxx.xxx:2083/ *- 100% working*

---

Through **CloudFlare**:

https://example.com/ *- 100% working*

https://example.com:2053/api *- 50% error from CloudFlare: 525 SSL* handshake failed

https://example.com:2083/ *- 50% error from CloudFlare: 525 SSL handshake failed*

---

I configured my servers to use ports reserved for https connections:
https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169156-Which-ports-will-Cloudflare-work-with-

When I set up main server to use port :443 instead of :80 it obviously doesn't work since I don't have SSL on the server.

How should be the https://example.com:2053/api configured to work with CloudFlare?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [description of Flexible SSL](https://web.archive.org/web/20170417201602/https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170416-What-do-the-SSL-options-mean-)<sup>1</sup>:

> Flexible SSL: secure connection between your visitor and CloudFlare, but no secure connection between CloudFlare and your web server...**This setting will only work for port 443->80, not for the other ports we support like 2053**

In other words: what you want is not possible with Flexible SSL.

---

<sup>1</sup> Using an archived version of the page reflecting the time when the answer was written. The original page has changed in the mean time.

Comment: Thanks, so at the end I have to install SSL on my server and switch to other SSL option.

Comment: @DariuszSikorski does this mean you solved by making your backend SSL and frontend http (yet relied upon Cloudflare to make that part SSL)? facing a similar problem.

Comment: I can't find this matter mentioned anywhere in Cloudflare documentation. Is there a source for this answer?

Comment: @Villahousut: I'm not sure what your comment is about. Currently it addresses my answer - which just cites Cloudflare as source of the information and also links to this information. If you ask about something else then please make it clear.

Comment: Following the link above, it doesn't contain any text related to the ports mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @Villahousut: I see what you mean now. Looks like Cloudflare has changed the documentation in the mean time. My question now links to an archived version of the documentation which contains the statement I've cited.